# Not able to build webdriver java code with ant build.xml file

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build, webdriver

So I installed ant and tried to write a xml file and tried to build my webdriver java code (in windows server 2003). But I'm unable to build the project. It throws so many errors.
Here is my build file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project default="run" name="title">
<target name="run" depends="compile">
</target>
<target name="compile">
<javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="./src" destdir="staging"/>
</target>
</project>
```

Here is the build failed error messages I'm getting

```
 [javac] Compiling 4 source files to G:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\eworkspace\Sample\staging
[javac] G:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\eworkspace\Sample\src\Login.java:1: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[javac] import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
[javac]                           ^
[javac] G:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\eworkspace\Sample\src\Login.java:2: error: package org.openqa.selenium.firefox does not exist
[javac] import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
[javac]                                   ^
[javac] G:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\eworkspace\Sample\src\lib_files\Login.java:7: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[javac] import org.openqa.selenium.By;
[javac]                           ^
[javac] G:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\eworkspace\Sample\src\lib_files\Login.java:8: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[javac] import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
[javac]                           ^
[javac] G:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\eworkspace\Sample\src\lib_files\Login.java:9: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
[javac] import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
[javac]
```

Can someone tell me what is going on ?
                          ^

Comment: Have you added selenium java jar file to classpath?

Comment: I did add G:\eclipse\selenium-2.33.0\selenium-java-2.33.0.jar to path variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add classpath ref as shown below.

```
<javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="./src" destdir="staging" 
classpathref="classpath" />
```

Comment: I ended-up getting this error G:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\eworkspace\Sample\build.xml:9: Reference classpath not found.

Comment: Can someone explain me what exactly is it doing ?

Comment: Then, kindly add `G:\eclipse\selenium-2.33.0\selenium-java-2.33.0.jar` to the CLASSPATH variable in environment variables.

Comment: I added something like `<path id="classpath"> 
<pathelement location="G:\eclipse\selenium-2.33.0\selenium-java-2.33.0.jar"/> 
<pathelement location="G:\eclipse\sikuli-script.jar"/> 
</path>`  So that error is gone. But it is showing 16 other errors in code like `:16: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;` so do I need to add all the JAR files in selenium ?

Comment: Im getting error only for this package 16: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^

Comment: Download testng from [here](http://testng.org/testng-6.8.zip) and add the file to CLASSPATH as you did for other jar files.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone tell me what is going on ?

The Jar containing the relevant classes is apparently not on the compile-time class-path.

Comment: Note that the c;ass-path is basically 'Java 101'.  Until you understand what it is and how to use it, best to steer clear of complex 3rd party projects.